# Magento 2: Error After Installing Sample Data using Composer

Tags: composer, sample-data, magento-2.1.8

Im using **Magento 2.1.8** and I already installed the **sample data** using composer but after running this commands setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, indexer:reindex, cache:clean, cache:flush and changing the permission I have this error from the CustomerSample data

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Setup version for module 'Magento_CustomerSampleData' is not specified

Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Setup version for module 'Magento_CustomerSampleData' is not specified
#0 /var/www/devsvr1/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(56): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isModuleVersionEqual('Magento_Custome...', '2.0.0')
#1 /var/www/devsvr1/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(79): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isSchemaUpToDate('Magento_Custome...')
#2 /var/www/devsvr1/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(55): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->getDbVersionErrors()
#3 /var/www/devsvr1/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /var/www/devsvr1/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#5 /var/www/devsvr1/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /var/www/devsvr1/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /var/www/devsvr1/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#8 /var/www/devsvr1/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(68): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /var/www/devsvr1/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /var/www/devsvr1/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#11 /var/www/devsvr1/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /var/www/devsvr1/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#13 /var/www/devsvr1/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#14 {main}
```

can anyone help me to fix this?
I already check the module of CustomerSampleData and there's a setup version.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by increasing the max_execution_time and reinstalling the SampleData